# check time period condition is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, if-statement

***functionality:***

when user click on a button, it will check on the condition if the time is between 6pm to 11pm of the day. If the time condition is met, it will show page A, else of the time is other than between 6pm to 11pm, it will show page B.

***Issue:***

I need help/assistance to have the syntax on how to do a conditional check for time that is between 6pm to 11pm -> show pageA else -> show pageB. I am unfamiliar on how to create the conditional check on checking if the condition satisfy between the time of 6pm to 11pm and the else factor

Hence the functional code is as follows :

```js
isDrive = false;

if (isDrive == true) {

  //check if time is between 6-11pm, show PageA_Video page, else show PageB_Video page
  if () {
    $("#PageA_Video").show();
    $("#PageB_Video").hide();
  } else if () {
    $("#PageA_Video").hide();
    $("#PageB_Video").show();
  }
} else if (isDrive == false) {
  $("#PageB_Video").show();
  $("#PageA_Video").hide();
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the time from?

Comment: @Xotic750, using system time. If system time shows 6pm, it will satisfy the condition and all the way till the system time shows 11pm, it will still satisfy the condition. else, if the system time doesn't show between 6pm to 11pm, it show pageB_video

Comment: So it doesn't matter if the system time is incorrect or what the timezone is?

Comment: @Xotic750 I believe that the user would have set the timezone in their computer system. System time taken from the system itself.

Comment: Sure, but if I'm in Australia and you are in US and we have the correct timezones set on our systems, the local time will be different. And, even with the correct timezone set and even if using UTC, I am able to modify my system time so that it is between 6pm and 11pm. So how important is this?

Comment: @Xotic750 lets ignore user interference with system time and base on whatever current time that the system is set and saved

Comment: Then just accept the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date` to get the time.

```js
isDrive = false;

if (isDrive == true) {

  //check if time is between 6-11pm, show PageA_Video page, else show PageB_Video page
  var d = new Date();
  var h = d.getHours();
  if (h>=18 && h<23) {
    $("#PageA_Video").show();
    $("#PageB_Video").hide();
  } else {
    $("#PageA_Video").hide();
    $("#PageB_Video").show();
  }
} else if (isDrive == false) {
  $("#PageB_Video").show();
  $("#PageA_Video").hide();
}
```